# how to make privateGPT retrieving info only from local documents?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers, langchain, nlp-question-answering, gpt4all

I'm using [**privateGPT**](https://github.com/imartinez/privateGPT) with the default [**GPT4All**](https://github.com/nomic-ai/gpt4all) model (*ggml-gpt4all-j-v1.3-groovy.bin*) but also with the latest Falcon version. My problem is that I was expecting to get information only from the local documents and not from what the model "knows" already.

*Example*: If the only local document is a reference manual from a software, I was expecting privateGPT to not be able to reply to a question like: "Which is the capital of Germany?" or "What is an apple?"  because it's something is not in the local document itself.

privateGPT uses a local Chroma vectorstore to store embeddings from local docs. The [**langchain**](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain) retriever shouldn't get info only from those? what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Privategpt response has 3 components (1) interpret the question (2) get the source from your local reference documents and (3) Use both the your local source documents + what it already knows to generate a response in a human like answer.

You can switch off (3) by commenting out the few lines shown below in the original code and defining

```
docs = db.as_retriever(search_type="similarity", search_kwargs={"k":5}).get_relevant_documents(query)
```

as shown below. You can adjust parameter `{"k":5}` to get 5 or any number of sources listed.

The draw back is if you do the above steps, privategpt will only do (1) and (2) but it will not generate the final answer in a human like response. So essentially privategpt will act like a information retriever where it will only list the relevant sources from your local documents.

**Modified code**

```
while True:
    query = input("\nEnter a query: ")
    if query == "exit":
        break

    # Get the answer from the chain
    ####res = qa(query)
    ####answer, ####
    docs = db.as_retriever(search_type="similarity", search_kwargs={"k":5}).get_relevant_documents(query)

    # # Print the result
    # print("\n\n> Question:")
    # print(query)
    # print("\n> Answer:")
    # print(answer)

    # Print the relevant sources used for the answer
    for document in docs:
        print("\n> " + document.metadata["source"] + ":")
        print(document.page_content)
```

Comment: Thanks but I've figure that out but it's not what i need. What I mean is that I need something closer to the behaviour the model should have if I set the prompt to something like 
"""
Using only the following context: 
<insert here relevant sources from local docs>
answer the following question:
<query>
"""
but it doesn't always keep the answer to the context, sometimes it answer using knowledge that is not in the provided context.

Answer (score 1):

your expectation is not correct. private GPT just means it can run locally on your computer as well without internet. You can ingest documents and ask questions without an internet connection!

[From here](https://theresanaiforthat.com/ai/privategpt/#:%7E:text=PrivateGPT%20differs%20from%20ChatGPT%20in,more%20secure%20environment%20for%20users.)

> PrivateGPT is particularly useful for individuals or businesses that
> require conversations with ChatGPT but are concerned about sensitive
> personal or business information that might be revealed in the course
> of the interaction.
>
> The tool provides added security for private conversations while
> maintaining the utility of ChatGPT. The tool's simple login/sign-up
> process makes it easy for users to start generating text that is free
> of sensitive information without having to worry about the privacy
> implications.
>
> Overall, PrivateGPT provides an effective solution for individuals and
> organizations that want to use LLMs like ChatGPT but need the extra
> reassurance of privacy protection.